# In ruby, how do I declare the C++ equivalent of "static" function variables?

Tags: ruby, declaration

I'm trying to keep a hash local to one function that remembers its state between calls to the function. But I don't know how to declare it without a closure (as some users suggested in a similar thread).

I know C++ more thoroughly than ruby, and in C++, I would have ordinarily used a `static` local variable, like in the first example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx

I managed to hack something together in ruby using the `defined?` function:

```
def func x
  if not defined? @hash
    @hash = Hash.new
  end

  if @hash[x]
    puts 'spaghetti'
  else
    @hash[x] = true
    puts x.to_s
  end
end

func 1
func 1
```

This prints, the following, which is kind of what I want. The only problem is that `@hash` can be accessed outside of that function.

```
1
spaghetti
```

Is there any "cleaner", more preferred way to declare a variable with this behavior (without a factory)? I was going to create two or three variables like `@hash`, so I was looking for a better way to express this concisely.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Transliterating a C++ solution into Ruby probably isn't a good idea. It would probably make more sense to wrap your "functions with static locals" in a separate object.

Comment: In my actual problem, I was writing a function `generate_prime n` that generated the nth prime number, and another function `prime? n` that checked if its argument was prime. There would be a lot of repeated arguments for both functions, so I was trying to cache some of the results in Hashes/Bignum objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is pretty common in Ruby, but also so common you don't need to make a big fuss about it. All `@`-type instance variables are local to that instance only. Keep in mind "instance" generally refers to an instance of a class, but it can refer to the instance *of* the class as well.

You can use `@@` to refer to a class instance variable from the context of an instance, but this tends to get messy in practice.

What you want to do is one of the following.

A variable that persists between method calls, but only within the context of a **single** object instance:

```
def func(x)
  # Instance variables are always "defined" in the sense that
  # they evaluate as nil by default. You won't get an error
  # for referencing one without declaring it first like you do
  # with regular variables.
  @hash ||= { }

  if @hash[x]
    puts 'spaghetti'
  else
    @hash[x] = true
    puts x.to_s
  end
end
```

A variable that persists between method calls, but only within the context of **all** object instances:

```
def func(x)
  # Instance variables are always "defined" in the sense that
  # they evaluate as nil by default. You won't get an error
  # for referencing one without declaring it first like you do
  # with regular variables.
  @@hash ||= { }

  if @@hash[x]
    puts 'spaghetti'
  else
    @@hash[x] = true
    puts x.to_s
  end
end
```

This is usually made cleaner by wrapping the `@@hash` into a class method. This has the secondary effect of making testing easier:

```
def self.func_hash
  @func_hash ||= { }
end

def func(x)
  if self.class.func_hash[x]
    puts 'spaghetti'
  else
    self.class.func_hash[x] = true
    puts x.to_s
  end
end
```